# iphone:how to add colon(:) in number pad(numeric keyboard)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard

I want to add time in my textfield and for that as per client's  requirement I take a numberpad(numeric keyboard) but in number pad there is no option for colon(:) and to show the time in min:sec colon(:) is required.

then how can I add colon in number pad?

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not add anything to existing keyboards. Best option in this case would be to use UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation

```
[myTimeTextField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
```

UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation has both numbers as well and punctuations (colon included)

[image: see attached image]

Comment: but I don't want characters i.e. 'ABC'

Comment: Then the only option left is to create a customKeyboard by subclassing UIView class.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't add a button like "Done" to lower left, you can add a ":" button and when user pressed it you can add ":" to the textfield.

There is an old but useful tutorial about adding a button to Numeric Keyboard
http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Answer (score 0):

you can use three different textfield for hour, minute and second.

check out the[link](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) which modified the number pad